# std::sort and std::unique problem with a struct

Tags: c++, stl, operators, compilation, std

The following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct myStructDim
{
    int     nId;
    int     dwHeight;
    int     dwWidth;
};    

void main()
{
    ::std::vector<myStructDim>  m_vec_dim;

    ::std::sort(m_vec_dim.begin(), m_vec_dim.end());
    m_vec_dim.erase(
        ::std::unique(m_vec_dim.begin(), m_vec_dim.end()),
        m_vec_dim.end()
        );
}
```

will not compile with many errors, such as:

> error C2784: 'bool std::operator
>   ==(const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &)' :
>   could not deduce template argument for
>   'const std::vector<_Ty,_Alloc> &' from
>   'myStructDim'

I understand that I have to override an operator or two.

Which ones and how exactly please?

Thanks for the support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need comparison operators to express the "less-than" and "equality" relationships.  Defining stand-alone boolean functions `operator<` and `operator==` that take two arguments, each `const myStructDim&`, and perform the comparison exactly the way you require, is probably simpler than defining then as methods within the `struct`.

Comment: Yup. Wasn't sure about that. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Like others mentioned operator< and operator== would do the trick but I usually prefer to pass a comparision predicate.

I use C++0x lambdas in this example but it can be implemented without that.

```
   std::sort(
      vec_dim.begin(), 
      vec_dim.end(), 
      [] (myStructDim const & l, myStructDim const & r) {return l.nId < r.nId;}
      ); 

   vec_dim.erase( 
      std::unique(
         vec_dim.begin(), 
         vec_dim.end(),
         [] (myStructDim const & l, myStructDim const & r) {return l.nId == r.nId;}
         ), 
      vec_dim.end() 
      );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some form of comparison function for `sort`, and you need some form of equality function for `unique`.

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to have some kind of unique without having the operato> ? I mean I can understand that for unique I need an operator== (like apples are not chairs) but why should a chair be greater than an apple ??? I would have to implement an operator for some objects where it makes no sense ! maybe some kind of clusering would make more sense.
So I decided to implement what the question is for my self here is in my opinion a solution that makes more sense:

template inline
void uniques(listtype In,listtype& Out)
    {
    Out.resize(In.size());
    std::copy(In.begin(),In.end(),Out.begin());
    listtype::iterator it = Out.begin();
    listtype::iterator it2= Out.begin();
    it2++;
    int tmpsize = Out.size();

```
    while(it!=Out.end())
    {
    it2 = it;
    it2++;
    while((it2)!=Out.end())
        {
        if ((*it)==(*it2))
            Out.erase(it2++);
        else
            ++it2;
        }
    it++;

    }
}
```

maybe not the best solution but at the moment I don t know betters