# looking for maximum in the array of structs

Tags: c++, struct

I'm just a beginner in the learning stage.

I am supposed to arrange a struct of `point` (`x`,`y`,`z`) so that structure `p[n]` has the point with the greatest `x` stored in it. Is my method correct? If not, are there any simper methods to do this?

```
struct point 
{
    float x;
    float y;
} p[1000];

void sortptx(struct point *t, int ctr);  

int main()
{
    int n = 100;  
    sortptx(&p, n);  
    return 0;  
}  

void sortptx(struct point *t, int ctr)  
{
    float temp;  
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i < ctr-1; i++)  
    {
        if (t[ctr]->x < t[i]->x)  
        {
            temp = t[ctr]->x;  
            t[ctr]->x = t[i]->x;  
            t[i]->x = temp;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `t[i].x` etc. Note that `<` doesn't define a strict weak ordering on IEEE754 floats, so you have to be careful.

Comment: Why not just use std::sort( &p, &p + n, cmp_function ) ?

Comment: Homework?  If not, I'd suggest `std::sort` with a customized comparison functor.

Comment: here's an example of std::sort of struct:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640663/stdsort-and-stdunique-problem-with-a-struct

Comment: *" that the structure p[n] has the point with greatest x stored in it"* - You meant p[n-1] I guess.

Comment: its jus a assigment for a course i am taking so i wanna keep it simple

Comment: @Kerrek SB when we pass the pointer to the array of structure  in the function aren't we suppose to call them like t[i]->x ??

Comment: that's some ugly looking code with code blocks beginning on the same line as the first curly brace, and variable names like `t` and `ctr`

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a few bugs here:

1. As mentioned in the comments, `struct point *t` is either a pointer to a single `struct point`, or an array of points. It is *not* a pointer to an array of pointers to `struct point`. So `t[i]->x` should be `t[i].x`.
2. If `ctr` is intended to be the length of an array of points, `t[ctr]` will run off the end of the array, and could access uninitialized memory. In that case, `t[ctr-1]` would be the last element of the array.
3. Rather than swapping entire points, you are just swapping the x coordinates.

Comment: How am I supposed to swap both x and y ?? will this work         struct point temp;                                                          {temp= p[ctr-1];                                                        p[ctr-1]= p[i];                                                          p[i]=temp;}

Comment: @Lol4t0, read the question carefully. He doesn't want to sort the array; he just wants the point with the greatest X coordinate at the end of the array. @Tarun, yes, that code will work, as long as you declare `temp` as `struct point`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you don't want to sort it, but find `point` with maximum `x` and make sure it is stored at `p[n-1]`.

```
struct point 
{
    float x;
    float y;
} p[1000];
```

This is how it could look like:

```
void max(struct point *t, int ctr)  
{ 
    struct point temp;  
    int i;  
    for(i = 0; i < (ctr - 1); i++)  
    { 
        if (t[ctr - 1].x < t[i].x)  
        { 
            temp = t[ctr - 1];  
            t[ctr - 1] = t[i];  
            t[i] = temp;  
        }
    }  
}
```

This function takes `struct point *t` as an argument, which is pointer to first `point` just like `p` is. `t[i]` is `struct point` at index `i` (not pointer to `struct point`), so you use `.` instead of `->` when you access its members. And since you are indexing from zero, last element of an array of size `n` has index `n-1`, which is place where the `struct point` with the highest `x` will be stored.

Example:

```
int main ()  
{ 
    for(int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        p[i].x = 1;
        p[i].y = 3;
    }
    p[4].x = 7;

    int n = 100;  
    max(p, n);  

    cout << p[n - 1].x;

    return 0;  
}
```

output: `7`

Comment: Ok so when we call the function max(p,n) don't we have to pass the memory location of p; i mean should't we call max(&p, n) instead.

Comment: I have updated my question. Note that `int i[10];` allocates on stack memory block of size so that 10 integers can be stored and `i` is pointer pointing to first element of this array then. `max(&p, n)` would mean you are passing address of pointer -> first argument of this function would have to be `struct point**` then.